# Simple jquery slideup function

Tags: jquery

I'm calling this function but I need to slideup the parent div of the link that was clicked.

This function is called from a normal link:

```
function close(){
    $(this).slideUp('slow', function() {

    });
}
```

How do i reference the element that was clicked (link), then get it's grandparent?
I want to slideup not this links parent div, but the parent div of the link div.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
onclick="javascript:$(this).parent().slideUp('slow');"
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be: `$(this).parent().slideUp(....)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('div > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function() {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What this function does is:

1. binds the click on an element
2. when element is clicked, its parent slides up

so:

```
function close(){
   $('elementToSlideUp').click(function(evt) {
       jQuery(this).parent().slideUp('slow');
   });
}
```